# TF-IDF for data filtering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I've a list of raw document, already filtered and removed english stopwords:

```
rawDocument = ['sport british english sports american english includes forms competitive physical activity games casual organised ...', 'disaster serious disruption occurring relatively short time functioning community society involving ...', 'government system group people governing organized community often state case broad associative definition ...', 'technology science craft greek τέχνη techne art skill cunning hand λογία logia collection techniques ...']
```

and I've used

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
sklearn_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2', min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=False)
sklearn_representation = sklearn_tfidf.fit_transform(rawDocuments)
```

But I got a

```
<4x50 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 51 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and I cant interpret the result. So, am I using the right tool or have I to change the way?

My goal is to get the relevant word in each document, in order to perform a cosine similarity with other words in a query document.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do `sklearn_representation.todense()` and you will get a matrix. The output is a sparse matrix because of memory reasons. You will have to convert it to a dense matrix. This is NOT ADVISED for large datasets

Comment: `sklearn_representation.todense()` is equal to `sklearn_representation.toarray()`? I can't interpret why I got those values in my matrix and at which word the values in `[0][3]`, for examples, is related.

Comment: You will not get this directly. Do a `sklearn_tfidf.get_feature_names()` to get the word names, those will be your column headers, and then every row is just a document. You will have to consolidate this info on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often Pandas module can be used to better visualize your data:

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.SparseDataFrame(sklearn_tfidf.fit_transform(rawDocument),
                        columns=sklearn_tfidf.get_feature_names(),
                        default_fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   activity  american       art  associative  british    ...       system    techne  techniques  technology      time
0      0.25      0.25  0.000000     0.000000     0.25    ...     0.000000  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  0.000000
1      0.00      0.00  0.000000     0.000000     0.00    ...     0.000000  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  0.308556
2      0.00      0.00  0.000000     0.282804     0.00    ...     0.282804  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  0.000000
3      0.00      0.00  0.288675     0.000000     0.00    ...     0.000000  0.288675    0.288675    0.288675  0.000000

[4 rows x 48 columns]
```

Comment: Could I use the single token in the raw document as column index, with this data type? Could I, for example, get the tf-idf for "associative" token in the third row in this way `df[2]['ability']`?

Comment: @FedericoCuozzo, sure you can do it in a few ways: `df.loc[2, 'associative']` or `df.at[2, 'associative']`. You may want to read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)...